# Version of __CLASS__ that binds at run-time rather than at compile-time

Tags: php, runtime, subclass, classname, dynamic-binding

In the following PHP code I would like to replace the `__CLASS__` magic constant in the `Foo` class with a function `__X__()` (or something similar) so that when the method `hello()` is called from an instance `$bar` of the `Bar` class, it prints `hello from Bar` (instead of `hello from Foo`). And I want to do this 
without overriding `hello()` inside `Bar`.

So basically, I want a version of `__CLASS__` that binds dynamically at run-time rather than at compile-time.

```
class Foo {

  public function hello() {

    echo "hello from " . __CLASS__ . "\n";

  }

}

class Bar extends Foo {

  public function world() {

    echo "world from " . __CLASS__ . "\n";

  }

}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->hello();
$bar->world();
```

OUTPUT:

```
hello from Foo
world from Bar
```

I WANT THIS OUTPUT (without overriding `hello()` inside `Bar`):

```
hello from Bar
world from Bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simple use [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php), like this:

```
echo "hello from " . get_class($this) . "\n";
echo "world from " . get_class($this) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
hello from Bar
world from Bar
```