# PHP static factory method: dynamically instantiate instance of the calling class

Tags: php, static, runtime, subclass, factory

This PHP question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401274/version-of-class-that-binds-at-run-time-rather-than-at-compile-time), but is a bit different. I have a static factory method called `create()` which instantiates a class instance. I want the method to dynamically instantiate an instance of the (sub)class on which it is called. So, the class it instantiates must be determined at runtime. But I want to do this without having to redefine the static factory method in the subclass (and this would be perfectly valid in my example since the subclass has no new data members to initialize). Is this at all possible?

```
class Foo {

  private $name;

  public static function create($name) {

    //HERE INSTED OF:
    return new Foo($name);
    //I WANT SOMETHING LIKE:
    //return new get_class($this)($name);//doesn't work
    //return self($this);//doesn't work either

  }

  private function __construct($name) {

    $this->name = $name;

  }

  public function getName() {

    return $this->name;

  }

}

// the following class has no private data, just extra methods:

class SubFoo extends Foo {

  public function getHelloName() {

    echo "Hello, ", $this->getName(), ".\n";

  }

}


$foo = Foo::create("Joe");
echo $foo->getName(), "\n"; // MUST OUTPUT: Joe

$subFoo = SubFoo::create("Joe");
echo $subFoo->getHelloName(), "\n"; // MUST OUTPUT: Hello, Joe.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must create object using `Late Static Binding` - method [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) is useful. Second option is use `static` keyword.

Example:

```
class Foo 
{
    private $name;

    public static function create($name) 
    {
        $object = get_called_class();
        return new $object($name);
    }

    private function __construct($name) 
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class SubFoo extends Foo 
{
    public function getHelloName() 
    {
        return "Hello, ". $this->getName();
    }
}

$foo = Foo::create("Joe");
echo $foo->getName(), "\n";

$subFoo = SubFoo::create("Joe");
echo $subFoo->getHelloName(), "\n";
```

And output:

```
Joe
Hello, Joe
```

Comment: Because you must create object `SubFoo`, read about late state binding... And there is a point of question. `static` is also good.

Comment: well sorry I mean `static` not `self`

Comment: What downvote? I didn't downvote. If I accidentally downvoted and then upvoted a tenth of a second later perhaps that showed up somewhere, not sure whether the notification would be deleted by the SE code in this case. Anyways, if anyone downvoted it wasn't me. Regards.

Comment: Anyways, what's the advantage of using `get_called_class()` instead of `static`? Thanks.

Comment: `get_called_class()` can be used to retrieve a string with the name of the called class, but `static` creating object.

Answer (score 7):

`return new static();`

there is already reserved keyword `static`

Comment: Well, that doesn't work for me. The first call goes fine, but when I call `$subFoo->getHelloName()` I get the fatal error `Call to undefined method Foo::getHelloName()`. It looks like `self` is binding at compile-time and not at run-time as I need it to bind. I've updated my code to show this.

Comment: oh sorry my bad, it is `static` keyword

Comment: OK, `return new static($name)` works for me. Please update your answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, It is possible with late static binding feature of php.

Instead of

```
$foo = Foo::create("Joe");
echo $foo->getName(), "\n"; // MUST OUTPUT: Joe

$subFoo = SubFoo::create("Joe");
echo $foo->getHelloName(), "\n"; // MUST OUTPUT: Hello, Joe.
```

try this

```
echo parent::getName();
echo self::getHelloName();
```

Comment: Well, if I have a chain of subclasses `parent` wouldn't work anyways. I think using `static($parameterList)` is the best answer to what I was looking for.